# TinyMCE 6.4.2 - dynamically height of editor acording to content for read only mode

Tags: tinymce, blazor-webassembly, .net-7.0, tinymce-plugins, tinymce-6

I have integrated TinyMCE editor 6 to .NET 7 blazor web assembly app according to official doc.
https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/blazor-ref/
https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/blazor-cloud/

Nuget packages:

```
<PackageReference Include="TinyMCE" Version="6.5.0" />
<PackageReference Include="TinyMCE.Blazor" Version="1.0.4" />
```

I'm using TinyMCE Editor component also for 'read only' mode (The reason is that tiny mce is using iframe and the created article looks same in editor mode and readonly mode. I do not have to deal with css.) and I have issue with setting dynamically height of editor acording to content.

**I'm using currently `autoresize` plugin, but it has some bug and it not always resize editor correctly. Sometimes I can see just first 3 lines of text. This bug happens totally randomly.**

`MudCard` is rendered when `_html != null`, otherwise loading screen is shown.

```
<MudCard>
      <MudCardContent>
            <Editor
                Value="@_html"
                Conf="@_editorReadOnlyConfig"
                Disable=true
                ScriptSrc="/lib/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"
            />
     </MudCardContent>
</MudCard>
```

```cs
    private readonly Dictionary<string, object> _editorReadOnlyConfig = new()
    {
        { "plugins", new string[] { "autoresize" } }, // https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/opensource/autoresize/
        { "toolbar", false },
        { "menubar", false },
        { "statusbar", false },
    };
```

Any ideas how to deal with this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I did nasty hack to fix `autoresize` plugin bug. I try to execute `autoResizeCommand` command every 100 ms until it succeeds. For some reason Editor is loading too long and executing command to early fails. I have tried to execute this command as a response to some Tiny MCE editor event, but without success. I have also created issue on github `tinymce-blazor` [repository](https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce-blazor/issues/69).
It is either only `autoresize` plugin bug, or `tinymce-blazor` nuget package bug.

```cs
    protected async override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        bool success;
        do
        {
            await Task.Delay(100);
            success = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<bool>("autoResizeCommand ");
        }
        while (!success);

        await base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }
```

```js
window.autoResizeCommand = () => {
    try {
        const global = typeof window !== 'undefined' ? window : global;
        if (global.tinymce && global.tinymce.activeEditor) {
            global.tinymce.activeEditor.execCommand('mceAutoResize');
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    } catch (e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```